# Faceted search does not correctly sort data with Š character

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure Search index containing some random car make data. One of those data items is for Skoda, but it happens to start with a 'Š'.

When I experimented with querying that data as a faceted search, I wanted the makes ordered. Here's my prototpye code for doing that:

```
var queryResults = searchIndexClient.Documents
    .Search(
        string.Empty,
        new SearchParameters
        {
            Facets = new List<string>
            {
                "make,count:1000,sort:value"
            },
            Top = 0
    });
```

In the returned data, the makes are indeed ordered correctly, however 'Škoda' appears at the bottom of the list. So I'm guessing I need to do something in order to get Azure Search to deal with that unicode character when it's sorting, but I have no idea what I need to do.

EDIT:

I used `Postman` to query the serch index, using the same faceted search params as mentioned above:

`docs?$select=make&facet=make,count:1000,sort:value`

Here is a trimmed subset of the JSON that was returned, which shows `škoda` appearing at the bottom. Note that in our test data we also have `skoda` in the list which is correct - both appear in the source index data.

```
{
  "@search.facets": {
    "make@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2015_02_28.QueryResultFacet)",
    "make": [
      {
        "count": 178,
        "value": "rover"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "rover / austin"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "rover mg"
      },
      {
        "count": 529,
        "value": "saab"
      },
      {
        "count": 3835,
        "value": "seat"
      },
      {
        "count": 3851,
        "value": "skoda"
      },
      {
        "count": 817,
        "value": "smart"
      },
      {
        "count": 12934,
        "value": "volkswagen"
      },
      {
        "count": 3922,
        "value": "volvo"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "vw scirocco gti"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "w67 6olf"
      },
      {
        "count": 3,
        "value": "westfield"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "value": "wiesmann"
      },
      {
        "count": 3,
        "value": "wolseley"
      },
      {
        "count": 1,
        "value": "zbmw"
      },
      {
        "count": 5,
        "value": "škoda"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It could be a bug. Would you mind sharing an example of the facet results where Škoda is sorted incorrectly?

Comment: @BruceJohnston I have edited my question with some sample data. If you need to any more info, please give me a shout.

Comment: Thanks. We'll look into it and update you with our findings.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Thanks for taking the time to look into this. That's awesome :)

Comment: @BruceJohnston I was just curious as to whether your team had any free time to take look into this oddity since I last commented?

Comment: Not yet. It's assigned to someone else on my team; I'll check with him.

Comment: @BruceJohnston Thanks for that, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a known limitation in Azure Search. Values of facets are sorted using binary order. The oddity you observed, škoda appearing at the bottom of the list, is expected. We are planning to incorporate more advanced collation algorithm in this case but don't have a fixed date yet. Please help us prioritize by creating a request on our [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

At this time, the only way to workaround the issue is to preprocess the facet values and store normalized (lowercased and diacritics removed) strings in the column.

We apologize for the inconvenience. We will inform you as soon as we make progress.

Thanks.

Nate

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the situation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [Text normalization for case-insensitive filtering, faceting and sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers) feature that's in Preview.

You can update your index to use this "normalizer" feature for the fields in which you'd like case-insensitive faceting operations. You don't need to preprocess the facet values anymore.

The "standard" normalizer is pre-defined and will include lowercasing and ascii-folding (removing accents). If you'd like other filters to be applied, please look at [predefined and custom normalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers#predefined-normalizers)